# Add new Raid 10 Array to Existing Dell PowerEdge R630, VMWare esxcli host 5.5

Tags: raid, dell, dell-poweredge, raid10

We have an existing Server (Dell PowerEdge R630 - Perc H703P Raid Controller ) running VMWare host 5.5.  The server has 2 existing Raid 1 arrays.  We would like to add an additional Raid 10 array (4 HD around 500GB each) in the slots.  I have already inserted the new drives in the available bays.  The server sees the new HDs as foreign.

My question is How do I add these new 4 HDs into a new VD (Virtual Drive) Raid 10 without blowing away or deleting the current VDs (2 existing) on the system? I want to keep the existing VDs and data in tact and just create a new Datastore for VMWare.

When I went to bios and to set up a new VD... that option ("Create New VD") was greyed out. I only saw the option to import.

Attached relevant images:

[image: Current VDs]

[image: New Drives]

[image: Foreign View]

[image: Foreign View cont]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your screenshots it looks like the drives you have inserted were a part of a raid-10 array once in the past on the different system. From here you have two options:

1. Import foreign configuration (VD Mgmt, F2, Foreign Config and Import). This is safest option, but the VD imported will contain data from the old system that once hosted these disks.
2. Clear foreign configuration (VD Mgmt, F2, Foreign Config and Clear). All information on this foreign array will be lost, drives will change from Foreign to Ready and after that you can create a new array as you like.

Comment: I went ahead and cleared the foreign configuration and was able to rebuild a raid10 on the disks.  Thanks for your answer!